# Get tags$div object (titlebar) to extend to screen edge (R Shiny app)

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am trying to make a title bar for my Shiny app using a div object with an h3 header inside. I have the padding and margin both set to 0px, but there is still a pesky white gap around the edge. When I have used dashboardHeader in the past, this gap is not there, so it doesn't seem to be an inherent component to Shiny.

code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
              tags$div(
                       id = 'titlebar',
                       
                      ## App title
                      HTML('<h3 id="apptitle"><span>SD Card Processing App</span></h3>')
                      ), # div
              tags$style('
                         #titlebar {
                                    position: relative;
                                    margin: 0px;
                                    padding: 0px;
                                    background-color: #3c8dbc;
                                    height: 80px;
                                   }
          
                         #apptitle {
                                    position: relative;
                                    top: 30px;
                                    left: 130px;
                                    color: white;
                                   }

                         #apptitle span {
                                         background-color: #367fa9;
                                         padding-top: 28px;
                                         padding-bottom: 24px;
                                         padding-right: 20px;
                                         padding-left: 20px;
                                        }
                        ')
             ) # fluidPage
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This should do it. `#titlebar {margin: -20px;}`

Comment: @YBS this worked as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the edge whitespace on left and right, wrap your "titlebar" div in a `fluidRow`.

```
fluidRow(tags$div(id = 'titlebar',
                  ## App title
                  HTML('<h3 id="apptitle"><span>SD Card Processing App</span></h3>')
))
```

If you want a title bar that has no whitespace on left, top, or right, you can start with something as simple as:

`fluidRow(tags$div(id = 'titlebar1', tags$h3('title')), style="background-color: cyan;")`

and then adjust style details to your liking.